# What could be regex for below logs?

Tags: awk, sed

I want to remove numbers from first bracket and keep all the rest of the bracket intact.

```
Mar 17 00:03:13   %ASA-5-106100: access-list   permitted tcp  10.252.0.165(50811) ->  172.19.26.33(4902) 
Mar 17 00:03:16   %ASA-5-106100: access-list   permitted tcp  10.252.0.166(54563) ->  172.19.26.33(4902) 
Mar 17 00:03:28   %ASA-5-106100: access-list   permitted tcp  10.252.0.222(38071) ->  172.19.26.33(4902) 
Mar 17 00:03:41   %ASA-5-106100: access-list   permitted tcp  10.252.0.222(38074) ->  172.19.26.33(4902) 
Mar 17 00:03:45   %ASA-5-106100: access-list   permitted tcp  10.252.0.221(17868) ->  172.19.26.33(4902) 
Mar 17 00:03:58   %ASA-5-106100: access-list   permitted tcp  10.252.0.166(54572) ->  172.19.26.33(4902) 
Mar 17 00:03:58   %ASA-5-106100: access-list   permitted tcp  10.252.0.166(54573) ->  172.19.26.33(4902) 
Mar 17 00:03:58   %ASA-5-106100: access-list   permitted tcp  10.252.0.166(54574) ->  172.19.26.33(4902) 
Mar 17 00:04:14   %ASA-5-106100: access-list   permitted tcp  10.252.0.165(50826) ->  172.19.26.33(4902) 
Mar 17 00:04:16   %ASA-5-106100: access-list   permitted tcp  10.252.0.166(54580) ->  172.19.26.33(4902) 
Mar 17 00:04:28   %ASA-5-106100: access-list   permitted tcp  10.252.0.222(38088) ->  172.19.26.33(4902) 
Mar 17 00:04:45   %ASA-5-106100: access-list   permitted tcp  10.252.0.221(17881) ->  172.19.26.33(4902)
```

I want to keep (4902) intact but want to take out first bracket with their numbers as well.

Is this correct to use?

```
awk '{sub('()'..... dst'()'," dst")}1'
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Any suggestion for this one ?

Comment: I have just added my answer, let me know if that helps you.

Comment: You can't use single quotes inside a single-quote-delimited script. That applies to any UNIX tool and includes the fact you can't even use them escaped (`\'`).

Answer (score 4):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed 's/([0-9]*)//' logfile
```

Answer (score 2):

To *take out first bracket with their numbers as well* in awk:

```
$ awk '{sub(/\([^)]*\)/,"")}1' foo
Mar 17 00:03:13   %ASA-5-106100: access-list   permitted tcp  10.252.0.165 ->  172.19.26.33(4902) 
Mar 17 00:03:16   %ASA-5-106100: access-list   permitted tcp  10.252.0.166 ->  172.19.26.33(4902)
```

Answer (score 2):

@Bhavik: try:

```
awk '{sub(/\([0-9]+\)/,"");print}'   Input_file
```

It removes the very first occurrence of (all digits and then ). Thenn it prints the line from Input_file.